# Why quartz.net does not execute all my code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net

I am using a task scheduled using quartz.net in mvc, but unfortunately not all of my code runs completely and ignores most of the code steps.
After much effort and comparison with previous examples, I realized that the Execute function inherited from the IJOB class is a async type, and after calling in global.asax, I have to define it as follows, in which case it does not execute the code completely And ignores part of it.
Thanks for the help because it really bothered me
Global.asax:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        ConfigureStoryQuartzJobs().Wait();

    }



    public static  async Task ConfigureStoryQuartzJobs()
    {
        DateTimeOffset startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<CheckContent>()
                                  .WithIdentity("job1")
                                  .Build();
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                         .StartAt(startTime)
                                         .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInMinutes(5).RepeatForever())
                                         .Build();
        ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler sc = await sf.GetScheduler();
      await  sc.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
       await sc.Start();

    }
}
```

job :

```
 public class CheckContent : IJob
{

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
      await  RelaseContent.SendStory();
      await  RelaseContent.SendPost();
      await  RelaseContent.SendAlboum();
    }
}
```

Comment: which parts are ignored, and how did you determine it?

Comment: Executes only part of the first function and refuses to execute after the page is loaded

Comment: In my opinion, the async function should not be called in application_start, and I have used the Wait () function to solve this problem, which can be ignored at the end of the code operation, but I have no other idea about this.

Comment: the `Wait()`  call is somehow "dangerous". You are blocking the thread that handle this. Could you first try to change the your main function as `async void Application_Start` and use `await ConfigureStoryQuartzJobs()` as last line, instead of the `Wait()` ?

Comment: or maybe, without `await` it's fire and forget, maybe that's what should be done (remove all the `await` and async from `ConfigureStoryQuartzJob`). You just want to start the scheduler and let it run in background

Comment: I also tested this option, it has no effect

Comment: I was also thinking of deleting all Async and Await, but when we inherit from IJOB, the method must be of the Async type.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas for background work?